# Media queries / responsive webpage

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a responsive webpage with my site here: https://chunzg.github.io/about.html

I have made a flex container for the photo and text.

Have used the media query below to first test on my laptop screen :

```
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 300px) 
  and (max-device-width: 600px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) { 
   .sidebar {
    width: 100%;
   }
   .photo {
    width: 100%;
   }
   .text {
    width: 100%;
   }
}
```

but it doesn't work - nothing changes. I would like the sidebar, photo and text to be stacked vertically on top of one another if I am looking at it on a narrow screen.

I know I must be doing something wrong but just don't have enough experience to know what needs to change

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Hey I am giving a reference:https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries_ex.asp
I couldnt understand the exact question but I think it should be like this:

```
/* On screens that are 992px wide or less, go from four columns to two columns */
    @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
   .sidebar {
    width: 100%;
   }
   .photo {
    width: 100%;
   }
   .text {
    width: 100%;
   }
}
```

In my code I scripts lets webpage to change width by 100 if the screen size is less than 600 or equal to 600.(Maybe it can be usefull for your ipad or small devices screen)

Also why did you used min and max at the same time?

Note that I am not professional but I have had some experiences with css so that my answer maybe could not be the solution. But lets try this.

Comment: Thanks! It didn't work but the W3 reference was helpful. I found on there they suggest to write the following code if you use flex boxes which is what I did.
`@media screen and (max-device-width: 600px) { 
   .row {
    flex-direction: column;
   }
}`
However this still doesn't work...

Comment: @media screen and (max-device-width: 600px) { .row { flex-direction: column; } } that .row means it is a class and flex-direction means one onther the other.

Comment: .row is a class but in your code there is no .row class

Comment: Ok I changed it to .container as that contains all my flex boxes but it still doesn't do anything... :/

Comment: yes i did... so confused why it's not working! thank you for your help

Comment: ıf my answer is helpfull can you please add tick mark?